# Is there any problem with drivers when lshw shows serial and power as unclaimed?

Tags: drivers

Recently I set up a new server with Ubuntu Server 12.04. The motherboard model is : Gigabyte H81M-DS2V. I think I have some problem with the drivers. Here is the output of `lshw`:

```
*-serial UNCLAIMED
         description: SMBus
         product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
         version: 05
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:f0519000-f05190ff ioport:f040(size=32)

 *-power UNCLAIMED
   description: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
   product: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
   vendor: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
   physical id: 1
   version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
   serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
   capacity: 32768mWh
```

Comment: Are you experiencing any specific troubles? I'm having the same situation on Lenovo IdeaPad-Z500-Touch and trouble with recognition of a PCI card <-> USB 2.0 adapter (just as input, I'll ask my own question if I don't get it sorted out)

Answer (score 0):

I've same case:

```
    *-serial UNCLAIMED
         description: SMBus
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
         version: 05
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:e9630000-e96300ff ioport:8000(size=32)

  *-power UNCLAIMED
       description: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       product: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       vendor: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       physical id: 2
       version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       capacity: 32768mWh
```

`dmesg | grep -i conflict`

```
[   19.286124] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000008000-0x000000000000801f SystemIO conflicts with Region \_SB_.PCI0.SBUS.SMBI 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)
```

`dmesg | grep ACPI`

```
[   19.286124] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000008000-0x000000000000801f SystemIO conflicts with Region \_SB_.PCI0.SBUS.SMBI 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[   19.286144] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
```

It seems that ACPI is handling device instead of native driver. Just to confirm, I booted my machine with `acpi=off`, Native driver (`i801_smbus`) was used:

```
    *-serial
         description: SMBus
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
         version: 05
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
         resources: irq:18 memory:e9630000-e96300ff ioport:8000(size=32)
```

For that `*-power` device, I couldn't make any advance.

Related Links:

- [Debian Bug #602128: ACPI Conflict (Hardware in risk)](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=602128)
- [[lm-sensors] i2c-i801 module conflict with 3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller [8086:3b30]](http://lists.lm-sensors.org/pipermail/lm-sensors/2010-September/029359.html)